# Personalizar páginas de error

Tags: .htaccess

Tengo un fichero llamado `error.php` al que quiero enlazar en el caso de que me devuelva un error 404. Lo hago a través de htaccess con el siguiente código:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

Los ejemplos que veo usan siempre la extensión html, no sé si es obligatorio, pero necesito usar PHP.

Me gustaría saber si quiero usar una página de mantenimiento, ¿tengo que usar el mismo código de error?

Answer (score 0):

En realidad no lo debes hacer.

Para redireccionar a páginas de mantenimiento debes usar el códgio 503 en el .htaccess

Aquí una manera de hacerlo para Wordpress https://wpdirecto.com/poner-wordpress-modo-mantenimiento-3318/

Si usas un CMS como Joomla el mismo framework soporta una página u mensaje de mantenimiento que puede ser personalizado.

Espero que te sirva...

Comment: Perdón, pero en ningún momento había de WordPress, Joomla o un framework. Hasta donde entiendo, se pregunta cómo hacerlo en el .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Rutas absolutas:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.tudominio.com/404.php

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.tudominio.com/folder/error/404.php
```

Sin olvidar las típicas configuraciones útiles del `.htacess`

```
RewriteBase / 
RewriteEngine On
```

A mi me funcioná [así](http://nuriarincon.com/xcvchvbxcbcvbnvnv) en mi Hosting.
Además tengo estas otras lineas en el `php.ini`:

```
display_errors = on
allow_url_fopen = on
allow_url_include = on
```

Desconozco bastante estos temas asi que toda la info la saqué googleando

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

http://php.net/manual/es/configuration.file.php